# How to extract text based on font color from a cell with text of multiple colors and separate multiple words by Delimiter?

Tags: excel, text, colors, vba

[How to extract text based on font color from a cell with text of multiple colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514704/how-to-extract-text-based-on-font-color-from-a-cell-with-text-of-multiple-colors)

I have a column of data (A). The data in each cell in column (A) is half one color and half another color. I have to extract each word separated by delimiter if they are at different places. I tried the solution in the above link but unable to make changes to suit my purpose as i am a beginner for vba.  please suggest methods to sole this problem.

(A) Original..........(B) Red

abcdefgh..........abc, gh

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to help anyone to help you. Can you show an actual example of what your source data looks like and what you want the output to be? You could use **bold** formatting to show which text is one colour and which is another (place ** before and after the text that should be bold).

Comment: @nekomatic, Sorry, if the question is not clear..What i meant was, Actually i have used another macro for spell check and the font color is changed to red of incorrect spelling, i have to extract the words. the macro in the above link was giving answer like this without any separator between two words.like below. i need to get like Connectores, longe
(A) Original..........(B) 
Connectores are very longe. ..........Connectoreslonge

Answer (score 2):

A User Defined Function (aka UDF) should get you through this.

```
Function udf_Whats_Colored(rTXT As Range, Optional iCLRNDX As Long = 3)
    Dim c As Long, str As String

    For c = 1 To Len(rTXT.Text)
        With rTXT.Characters(Start:=c, Length:=1)
            If .Font.ColorIndex = iCLRNDX Then
                If Not CBool(Len(str)) Or _
                   rTXT.Characters(Start:=c + (c > 1), Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = iCLRNDX Then
                    str = str & Mid(rTXT.Text, c, 1)
                Else
                    str = str & ", " & Mid(rTXT.Text, c, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next c
    udf_Whats_Colored = str

End Function
```

After considering all of the shades of red that are available, I opted for the simpler solution of `.ColorIndex = 3`. There is an optional parameter so that you can set your own [ColorIndex property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) number. If you need more colors, it should be a small matter to swap the code over to the [.Font.Color property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837437.aspx).

[image: Which Red Characters]

The syntax used in the above image in B2 is,

```
=udf_Whats_Colored(A2)
```

---

[image: ColorIndex Palette Table]
                     <sup>ColorIndex Palette Table</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the UDF, but if word contains only one red word it is giving me ", word". i don't want delimiter if there is single word. Original Color
abcgef , abc ...Here abc is red colored but from ur udf i am getting", abc", i don't need the comma for single words.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, Can you kindly suggest on how to solve this issue posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588557/parsing-multicolored-text-in-excel-spreadsheet-cell-into-multiple-cells?