# Parsing multicolored text in Excel spreadsheet cell into multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have sequence of colored text characters in a cell. I would like to parse it based on color to multiple cells as shown below. The colors are repeating. I tried to use some of the solutions already posted in this forum including the solution: [How to extract text based on font color from a cell with text of multiple colors and separate multiple words by Delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864958/how-to-extract-text-based-on-font-color-from-a-cell-with-text-of-multiple-colors]). But, could not achieve the results I want. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: you need to post your code and tell us what happens when you run it   "But, could not achieve the results I want" doesn't really give anyone much to go on to help you.

Comment: Sure! I am also continuously testing solutions. I will do that shortly.

Comment: another option could be parsing the cell value XML from `[H2].Value(11)` or `[H2].Value(12)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks right.

```
Option Explicit

Function udf_Color_Piece(rTXT As Range, Optional iNDX As Long = 1)
    Dim c As Long, seg As Long, clr As Long

    seg = 0
    clr = -9
    udf_Color_Piece = vbNullString

    For c = 1 To Len(rTXT.Text)
        With rTXT.Characters(Start:=c, Length:=1)
            If clr <> .Font.Color Then
                seg = seg + 1
                clr = .Font.Color
                If seg > iNDX Then Exit Function
            End If
            If seg = iNDX Then
                udf_Color_Piece = udf_Color_Piece & .Text
            End If
        End With
    Next c

End Function
```

[image]